# Update a variable outside of a component class from class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to dynamically update a decorator property.
Seems that it's possible to declare a variable outside of the class and use it in the decorator.
How can I update the `example` variable.

```
let example = 'this is just a test';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component-test',
    templateUrl: './component-test.component.html',
    styles: [example],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    providers: []
})
export class TestComponent extends IComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    example = "updated from inside class"; // HOW?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the variable again instead of assigning it

```
constructor(){
 example = 'Updated from inside class';
}
```

Comment: Don't forget "this" /// this.example = 'Updated from inside class';

Comment: The variable example is outside the class. The line with the comment //how will be removed. (else you are correct)

Comment: you're right but in that case I think the better / neater solution is to use services / subjects I'm sure it'll save them a lot of trouble in the future and contribute to a neater code since it's not a const, rather a simple variable.

Comment: `styles: [example],` which is used here but obviously, styles, didn't get updated